# Set up and run analytics jobs using the Azure Stream Analytics API for .NET

Tags: azure, rest, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to going through this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-dotnet-management-sdk) to be and running with stream analytic client in .net.

In Visual Studio I get an error in the GetCredentials method saying "UserTokenProvider does not contain a definition for LoginWithPromptAsync".

I am using, as required in the set up project, the following:

Microsoft.Azure.Management.StreamAnalytics -Version 2.0.0

Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication -Version 2.3.1

Which other method can I use, can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run analytics jobs using the Azure Stream Analytics API for .NET, you can use service principal to do auth.

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role to the sp

```
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n ""
```

2. Package

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Management.StreamAnalytics -Version 2.0.0
Install-Package Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication -Version 2.3.1
```

3. Code

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            string clientId = "23***b79c";
            string clientSecret = "";
            string ActiveDirectoryTenantId = "e****b";

            var credentials = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(ActiveDirectoryTenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

            StreamAnalyticsManagementClient streamAnalyticsManagementClient = new StreamAnalyticsManagementClient(credentials)
            {
                SubscriptionId = "e*****8"
            };
           var jobs = await  streamAnalyticsManagementClient.StreamingJobs.ListAsync();
            foreach (var job in jobs) {
                Console.WriteLine(job.Id);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer, this is really helpful. I've checked my Azure subscription and it might be a problem to get the permission to create a service principal. Could it be done in another way? Actually I can connect to a Synapse SQL Pool in my Azure and I use password and telephone code for that. Maybe this can be used for Stream Analytics?

Comment: @vinx Is that you want to use username and password to do auth?

Comment: Yes, I am actually using username, password and verification code to log in to a database in Azure. Would it be possible to use same method for Stream Analytics?

Comment: @vinx According to my test. It is Ok for me. I can use the method `UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync`;https://i.imgur.com/0gjx9Gz.gif

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Jim. Which version of Microsoft.Rest.Azure.Authentication are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication 2.3.1 and cannot find the method, UserTokenProvider.LoginWithPromptAsync. Are you using and older version probably?

Comment: @vinx I use NET framework 4.7. This is my package.config: https://pastebin.pl/view/0b2b0732

Comment: thanks a lot for update. I was using .NET core and that's why it couldn't work. I've changed to NET 4.7 and it works. Now I want to improve it by using **ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync**  and for this I need to create a Service Principle on my subscription, correct?

Comment: @vinx Yes. You need to create a service pricinpal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/create-azure-service-principal-azureps?view=azps-6.0.0.